# Entity Framework DbSet performance usage

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbset

Having an `DbContex`:

```
public class ProductsContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Product> Products;
}
```

I can do this:

```
Product product = _context.Products.Find(1);
```

I want to do that in an generic way

```
IDbSet<T> set = _context.Set<T>();
T entity = set.Find(1);
```

There are any Entity Framework related performance difference between the two or is the same thing?

Comment: I tested that some time ago with EF 4.1 and the difference was zero. But I suggest that you write a simple test loop and make a few test runs to convince yourself. It's a matter of 10 minutes...

Comment: @Slauma Thanks. I will trust you.

Comment: _context.Products == _context.Set<Product>()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [query-profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163749.aspx) for performance issue.

Comment: @ramaral, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307326/c-sharp-generic-vs-not-generic-performance

Comment: @ramaral Code performance? Are you joking?  Your db interaction will take 10000x more time than the dirfferene in code runtime, so it is not even measurable the moment you hit an external server.

Comment: @TomTom Yes I know! But my question is if are any significant differece between the two.

Comment: @TomTom: Unfortunately EF has a lot of surprises about its pure code performance (mainly probably because heavy reflection is involved). Things like `Attach`ing an object (= just code in memory) can be slower than loading it from the DB. When inserting lots of objects change detection (= internal `DetectChanges` calls) can consume much more time than the actual writing into DB, etc., etc.