# Write Delegates without messing up the code

Tags: c#, delegates

I am writing delegates as like this.

```
  delegate void MyMethod(string arg1, string arg2);
  MyMethod mm;
```

I don't know why it needs two lines to declare a single delegate. If my class has 20 delegates, I need to write 40 line of code. 
Can anybody tell me a way to write this in one line of code ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you use .NET Framework 3.5 or later you can use [Func<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.90).aspx) and [Avtion<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) delegates, instead of declaring new delegate type each time.

Comment: Is there any perfomance difference between Func and Delegate ?

Comment: This - [c# generic vs not-generic performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307326/c-sharp-generic-vs-not-generic-performance), should help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're declaring two very different things here:

- The first line declares a delegate *type* called `MyMethod`
- The second line declares a *field* of that delegate type

It's important to understand the difference, because then you can work out when you really want to declare a new delegate type and when you *just* want to declare a field of an existing delegate type. If your class has 20 delegate fields, you almost certainly don't want to declare a new type for each of them. If they've got the same signature, you could use a single type... or better, just use one of the framework types such as `Action<...>` or `Func<...>`.

```
Action<string, string> mm;
```

(There are `Action` delegates for `void` return types, and `Func` delegates for non-`void` return types, with different numbers of parameters, all expressed generically. Look at MSDN for more details.)

Comment: What about types such as Tuples? I've been told that usually they're only used while prototyping, but ought to be wrapped in a class before going into production.

Comment: Is there any perfomance difference between delegate and Func ?

Comment: @YesudassMoses Func is delegate. `Func<T1, T2>` defined like `delegate T2 Func<in T1, out T2>(T1 t)`.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard: I'm not sure where tuples come in here... they're not delegate types.